# what is a good way to link exclusive statements in prolog?

Tags: prolog

We were asked to write a menu based calculator on an exam where we were to return control to the menu once the desired calculation had been performed.

I wrote the following code as my solution and while the professor deemed it as correct I still think there must be a better way to return control to the menu after the the first clause to table(A,N) returns false.
Please note that I've redacted quite a bit of my original code that was irrelevant to my question.

```
    menu :-
      write('Enter a choice: '),
      read(C),
      choice(C).

    choice(1) :-
      table(5).

    table(N) :- 
      A is 1,
      start(A,N).

    table(A,N) :- 
      K is A*N, 
      write(K), 
      nl, 
      A1 is A+1, 
      A1=<10,
      table(A1, N)
      ; 
      menu.
```

I'm very new to prolog so the question might not be appropriately worded. Please let me know if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repeat/0` to loop forever.

```
menu :-
      repeat, % add this line
      write('Enter a choice: '),
      read(C),
      choice(C).

    choice(1) :-
      table(5).

    table(N) :- 
      A is 1,
      start(A,N).

    table(A,N) :- 
      K is A*N, 
      write(K), 
      nl, 
      A1 is A+1, 
      A1=<10,
      table(A1, N).
      % ;     % delete this line
      % menu. % delete this line
```